# Sonicwall networking

Tags: networking, sonicwall, static-routes

My Sonicwall LAN subnet is `192.168.1.0/24`

X0: LAN IP `192.168.1.253`

I also have intranet router `192.168.1.108` routing to `192.168.2.0/24` network. Internet is through WAN (`X1`) is all working fine.

My LAN PC's can connect to intranet `192.168.2.0/24` via static route from LANsubnet to `192.168.2.0/24` as `192.168.1.108` as gateway.

Now I have LAN2 `10.2.1.254` (`10.2.1.0/24`)on `X4` port.

I can access Internet from `LAN2`, now I want to allow  intranet from `LAN2`. What static routes do I need to make this work?

Comment: What? Can you try to clean this up and better explain what you need?

Comment: This is certainly a legitimate question, and my answer below solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Intranet router (**not your Sonicwall**) at 192.168.1.108 needs a static route for 10.2.1.0/24 added to 192.168.1.253.

The reason accessing the X0 subnet works fine with just a static route on **your** Sonicwall is because the Intranet router has an interface connected to that subnet. Since it is the default gateway for the clients on the other end, traffic can return just fine. In this case however, the X4 interface and it's subnet are only connected to the Sonicwall, and therefore another device that does not use the Sonicwall as it's default route will need a static route to reach it.